# Flask-login threading error

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to set up a basic authentication process using Flask-login and have the following code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = forms.LoginForm()
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        if database.validate_user(login_form.username.data, login_form.password.data):
            user = User(database.get_id(login_form.username.data), login_form.username.data)
            flask_login.login_user(user)
            return render_template('login.html', login_form = login_form )
    return render_template('login.html', login_form = login_form )
```

Inclusion of the login_user function causes me to get the following error and I'm having trouble working out why:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
  self._bootstrap_inner()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 702, in inner
  srv.serve_forever()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 539, in serve_forever
  HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 238, in serve_forever
  self._handle_request_noblock()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
  self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
  self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
  self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
  self.handle()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 232, in handle
  rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
  self.handle_one_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 267, in handle_one_request
  return self.run_wsgi()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209, in run_wsgi
  execute(self.server.app)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 197, in execute
  application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
  response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_exception
  self.log_exception((exc_type, exc_value, tb))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1560, in log_exception
  ), exc_info=exc_info)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 67, in error
  # If you don't want threading information in the log, set this to zero
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1506, in _LogErrorReplacement
  for hdlr in c.handlers:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
  return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
  response = self.process_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1858, in process_response
  self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 924, in save_session
  return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 363, in save_session
  val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
  payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
  json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
  return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
  return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 123, in dumps
  rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
  **kw).encode(obj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
  chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 80, in default
  return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
  o.__class__.__name__)

builtins.TypeError: Object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not JSON serializable
```

Could anyone point me in the direction of what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is happening here -> `user = User(database.get_id(login_form.username.data), login_form.username.data)`?

Comment: That is part of the flask-login code to define the session user as an instance of the User class to help managing user authentication.

Comment: Are you using flask-login `UserMixin` on `User`?

Comment: Exactly, yes, a very basic implementation of it:

`class User(flask_login.UserMixin):

    def __init__(self, id, email):
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
    
    def get_id(self):
        return id`

Comment: Did you specify a `user_loader` callback? https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works

Comment: Yes, I did. The only thing I can see from debugging is that the login_user function does not seem to be updating the session attributes that it should be for some reason.